# TSQL Rows Increase After Each Column Insert

Tags: python, sql-server

I am inserting data into a TSQL table. However, my rows increase after each column insert. So that after inserting 3 values into Column A, and 3 values into Column B, I end up with 6 rows in my table. It should only be 3 rows and two column. All my column have equal length, but after insert them into the table, I end up with 3 x 2 = 6 rows.

```
# python
for i in ColA:
    cur.execute("""
                INSERT INTO TAB(ColA) VALUES (?) """, i)
    cur.commit()

for i in ColB:
    cur.execute("""
                INSERT INTO TAB(ColB) VALUES (?) """, i)
    cur.commit()
```

When I check the data in SQL Server, I end up with 6 rows and 2 columns:

```
| ColA | ColB |
|-------------|
|  9   | Null |
|  7   | Null |
|  2   | Null |
| Null |   2  |
| Null |   6  |
| Null |   3  |
```

Comment: Then you need to change your insert statement to include both columns. Or change the second part to an update.

Comment: Based on this and your previous question, no offence intended, but I think you need to spend some time on some basic SQL tutorials learning how insert and update work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the two collections together (possibly using the zip function in Python) and then iterate through the result to generate your inserts, inserting both column values at once as
Sean Lange suggested.

Something like:

```
for tuple in zip(ColA, ColB):
    cur.execute("""
            INSERT INTO TAB(ColA, ColB) VALUES (?, ?) """, tuple[0], tuple[1])
    cur.commit()
```

(Untested, as I am not a Python programmer.)